# SPO Rest API call resulting in Empty Array

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to get all the files in a Document Library placed in a subsite. The Document Library is called `WorkInstructions`.
I am currently using Bearer access token.

[https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/manu/mfgoper/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/teams/manu/mfgoper/WorkInstructions')/Files](https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/manu/mfgoper/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27/teams/manu/mfgoper/WorkInstructions%27)/Files)

I can get the item count just not the data. Any help is appreciated.

Below is the API call:

[image]

Comment: I can see that you are showing a team site. Have you made sure that your user has sufficient user permission on the site and the Document Library?

Comment: Yes, I am the SP admin.

Comment: You may be the SP admin, but do you have permissions on the team site?